# Python/how to insert data from one table into another according to the data condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have a the first table

```
                   user_cnt             cost          acquisition_cost
channel         
facebook_ads            2726            2140.904643         0.79
instagram_new_adverts   3347            2161.441691         0.65
yandex_direct           4817            2233.111449         0.46
youtube_channel_reklama 2686            1068.119204         0.40
```

and the second

```
user_id        profit   source         cost_per_user    income  
8a28b283ac30   0.91   facebook_ads           ?           0.12
d7cf130a0105   0.63  youtube_channel         ?           0.17
```

The second table has more 200k rows, but i showed only two. So, i need to put "acquisition_cost" value from the first table to column "cost_per_user" in the second table according to the name of channel/source. For instance, on the first row in the second table cost_per_user should has value - 0.79 due to it's facebook_ads.

I will be grateful if someone can help me to solve this task.

First of all i tried to use the function:

```
I tried the function:
def cost (source_type):
    if source_type == 'instagram_new_adverts':
          return 0.65
    elif source_type == 'facebook_ads':
          return 0.79
    elif source_type == 'youtube_channel_reklama':
          return 0.40
    else: return 0.46

target_build['cost_per_user'] = target_build['source'].apply(cost)`
```

but i have to find another desicion without using of constants(*return 0.65*).

Another attemption was like this

```
for row in first_table['channel'].unique():
     second_table.loc[second_table['source'] == row, 'cost_per_user'] = first_table['acquisition_cost']
```

this code works only for the first four lines and for another it put zero value.

and the last idea was

```
second_table['cost_per_user'] = second_table['cost_per_user'].where(
   second_table['source'].isin(b.index), b['acquisition_cost'])
```

and again it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `pandas`. One possible solution is to use `pandas` version of inner join: [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging).

### Example

Suppose you don't want to modify either your first or second table, you can create a temporary table including just `channel` and `acquisition_cost` from the first table, but also changing the column names to `source` and `cost_per_user`. This can be implemented in various ways. One possible way, presuming your `channel` is an index, is shown below.

```py
temp_df = first_df.acquisition_cost.reset_index().rename(
    columns={'channel': 'source', 'acquisition_cost': 'cost_per_user'},
)
```

`temp_df` looks like this

```
                    source  cost_per_user
0             facebook_ads           0.79
1     instaram_new_adverts           0.65
2            yandex_direct           0.46
3  youtube_channel_reklama           0.40
```

Say your second table looks like this:

```
        user_id    profit                   source    income
0  c3519e80c071  0.773956            yandex_direct  0.227239
1  cc39ba469a08  0.438878     instaram_new_adverts  0.554585
2  a44a621e0222  0.858598             facebook_ads  0.063817
3  9dbf921b0959  0.697368  youtube_channel_reklama  0.827631
4  d45bf8fcab75  0.094177  youtube_channel_reklama  0.631664
5  57dbe1efd8b1  0.975622            yandex_direct  0.758088
6  1e0e3f1e13f7  0.761140     instaram_new_adverts  0.354526
7  27a7a7470ef4  0.786064  youtube_channel_reklama  0.970698
8  360dfd543fb5  0.128114            yandex_direct  0.893121
9  a31f46c26abb  0.450386     instaram_new_adverts  0.778383
```

You can run the `merge` call to attach `cost_per_user` to each `source`.

```py
new_df = pd.merge(left=second_df, right=temp_df, on='source', how='inner')
```

`new_df` would look like this

```
        user_id    profit                   source    income  cost_per_user
0  c3519e80c071  0.773956            yandex_direct  0.227239           0.46
1  57dbe1efd8b1  0.975622            yandex_direct  0.758088           0.46
2  360dfd543fb5  0.128114            yandex_direct  0.893121           0.46
3  cc39ba469a08  0.438878     instaram_new_adverts  0.554585           0.65
4  1e0e3f1e13f7  0.761140     instaram_new_adverts  0.354526           0.65
5  a31f46c26abb  0.450386     instaram_new_adverts  0.778383           0.65
6  a44a621e0222  0.858598             facebook_ads  0.063817           0.79
7  9dbf921b0959  0.697368  youtube_channel_reklama  0.827631           0.40
8  d45bf8fcab75  0.094177  youtube_channel_reklama  0.631664           0.40
9  27a7a7470ef4  0.786064  youtube_channel_reklama  0.970698           0.40
```

### Notes

Complication would arise if the `source` column of the second table does not have a one-to-one match to the `channel` in the first table. You will need to read the [doc on `merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging) to decide how you would want to handle that situation (e.g. use inner join to discard any mismatch, or left join to keep the unmatched `source` but receiving no `cost_per_user`).